# Pandas Data Frame: Add Column Conditionally On Past Dates and Values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm continuing to try to accomplish things in pandas which are easy in excel.  Consider the df:

```
   |  ID  |  Value  |  Date
0  |  A   |  .21    |  2010-01-01
1  |  A   |  .31    |  2010-02-01
2  |  A   |  .44    |  2010-02-15
3  |  B   |  .23    |  2010-01-01
4  |  C   |  .21    |  2010-02-01
5  |  C   |  .91    |  2010-02-15
```

Thoughts on the best way to add a new column which checks to see (a) if the value is greater than .30 and (b) whether or not the ID has a record (row) with an earlier date that is also greater than .30?

I would ideally like to record 'Yes' in a new column when the value is greater than .3, and it's the earliest date at which that ID has a value greater than .30; record 'No' where the value is less than .3 and the ID has no earlier record greater than .3; and record 'Already' whenever the ID has an earlier record with a value > .3.

So the output looks something like:

```
   |  ID  |  Value  |  Date        | Result 
0  |  A   |  .21    |  2010-01-01  | No
1  |  A   |  .31    |  2010-02-01  | Yes
2  |  A   |  .24    |  2010-02-15  | Already
3  |  B   |  .23    |  2010-01-01  | No
4  |  C   |  .21    |  2010-02-01  | No
5  |  C   |  .91    |  2010-02-15  | Yes
```

Thanks kindly for any input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way, create a function which acts on each ID subDataFrame to return a Series of No, Yes and Already:

```
In [11]: def f(x, threshold=0.3):
             first = (x > threshold).values.argmax()
             if x.iloc[first] > threshold:
                 return pd.concat([pd.Series('No', x.index[:first]),
                                   pd.Series('Yes', [x.index[first]]),
                                   pd.Series('Already', x.index[first+1:])])
             else:
                 return pd.Series('No', x.index)

In [12]: df.groupby('ID')['Value'].apply(f)
Out[12]:
0         No
1        Yes
2    Already
3        Yes
4         No
5        Yes
dtype: object

In [13]: df['Result'] = df.groupby('ID')['Value'].apply(f)

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
  ID  Value        Date   Result
0  A   0.21  2010-01-01       No
1  A   0.31  2010-02-01      Yes
2  A   0.29  2010-02-15  Already
3  B   0.23  2010-01-01      Yes
4  C   0.21  2010-02-01       No
5  C   0.91  2010-02-15      Yes
```

Comment: Hi, yes I've been trying to fix it.  The problem is that it's returning back false positives.  I.e. giving a result of 'Yes' at events below the threshold.  Does it matter that in reality I'm using this on a data frame with several columns?

Comment: I thought it only impacted cases where an ID only appears once in the dataset, and that if it only had one row that row got indexed 'First'.  This is not so.  I thought it might have to do with the datatype of the value column (float).  But this doesn't appear to be so because there are cases where the same value is correctly labelled 'no' for one id, and then 'labelled 'yes' for another.  The 'Already' function works splendidly.

Comment: @user1893148 ah, good spot, thanks for the comment, will fix my solution!

Comment: I think the existing method will work, if there's a way to reliably identify the 'first' index.  I was thinking maybe add a column which distinguishes true/false for above/below the threshold, and then group by id and t/f (and then back out the falses).  But I can't quite complete the idea in my head..

Comment: So the issue was that argmax found the 0th item if they were all False so I just special cased that (I also used values so I'd get the position rather than the label).